# Window Function / Aggregate Function / Interrupting Window

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Table looking like this (Cols A-D):

```
A        B           C                 D        E
----------------------------------------------------------
1        2011        2011-06-30        A        2013-06-30
1        2012        2012-06-30        A        2013-06-30 
1        2013        2013-06-30        A        2013-06-30 
1        2014        2015-06-30        B        2015-06-30 
1        2015        9999-12-31        A        9999-12-31 
2        2014        9999-12-31        C        9999-12-31 
2        2015        9999-12-31        C        9999-12-31 
2        2016        9999-12-31        C        9999-12-31
```

I try to create col E based on A-D via window functions. I need to calculate the max(C) without interruption of D (if it changes the next window should begin) ordered by A, B and C.

Comment: `select*,max(c) over (partition by D) from table`?.. next row have D='A' again?..

Comment: No, it won't work. Look at 5 row, it has D=A and C=9999-12-31, so E for rows 1-3 would be also 9999-12-31 and OP doesn't want that.

Comment: How come 5th row date derived, in which way it is different than first 3 rows of the data

Comment: The table represents a time-related mapping between A and D over time B. Here, the overall period should be recognized until a switch by D occurs. Therefore, the row 5 is different to the lines 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify adjacent groups.  One method uses a difference of window functions to identify the groups:

```
select t.*,
       max(c) over (partition by a, seqnum_a - seqnum_ad) as e
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as seqnum_a,
             row_number() over (partition by a, d order by b) as seqnum_ad
      from t
     ) t;
```

It is a bit hard to explain how the difference of row numbers works.  However, if you run the subquery and stare at the results, you'll probably see how it works.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to get the requested result

```
select t1.*,t2.C as E from table1 as t1
(select D,max(c) C from table1 group by D) as t2 on t1.D=t2.D
```

Comment: Does not work. Rows 1-3 will get 9999-12-31 instead of 2013-06-30

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński, it will fail but how come 5th row date derived, in which way it is different than first 3 rows of the data